# LineBreakMode - how does it works with SfRadioButton (syncfusion) in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Syncfusion docs write down that i can use LineBreakMode with SfRadioButton, but it doesn't work

```
<syncfusion:SfRadioGroup x:Name="RatingGroup">
  <syncfusion:SfRadioButton x:Name="first"> <-- LineBreakMode doesn't work in this tag !-->
    <syncfusion:SfRadioButton.Text>
      The communication between the company and me was good...
    </syncfusion:SfRadioButton.Text>
  </syncfusion:SfRadioButton>
</syncfusion:SfRadioGroup>
```

Could anyone give me a little help in this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: The translator throw exception that told me LineBreakMode is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your update, we suspected that you are using the older version of **Syncfusion.Xamarin.Buttons** nuget in your application. The required feature “**LineBreakMode**” is available from **17.3.0.14 release of Syncfusion.Xamarin.Buttons**.

To resolve this, please update the Nuget and used as per in below code snippet

```
<syncfusion:SfRadioGroup HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="150"  x:Name="RatingGroup">
    <syncfusion:SfRadioButton LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  x:Name="first">
        <syncfusion:SfRadioButton.Text>
            The communication between the company and me was good...
        </syncfusion:SfRadioButton.Text>
    </syncfusion:SfRadioButton>
</syncfusion:SfRadioGroup>
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

For more details please refer below [UG link](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/radio-button/visual-customization#linebreakmode).

Answer (score 0):

I used an older syncfusion release which doesn't contain LineBreakMode yet.